# Is there a way to specify which function to override?

Tags: d

```
interface A
{
    void f();
}
interface B
{
    void f();
}
class C : A ,B
{
// pseudocode 
    void A::a(){}
    void B::a(){}
}
```

Is there a way to have different implementations of `A::f` and `B::f` in the same class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When they both have the same signature, no*. If `A.f` is `void f()` and `B.f` is `int f()`, it's possible.

* actually, there is a way, if you accept that it's not doing exactly the same thing:

```d
interface A { string f(); }

interface B { string f(); }

class C : A {
    string f() { return "A"; }
    string bf() { return "B"; }
    
    // Pretend to be a B
    alias get this;
    B get() {
        auto that = this;
        return new class B {
            string f() { return that.bf(); }
        };
    }
}

unittest {
    auto c = new C();
    
    A a = c;
    B b = c;
    
    assert(a.f() == "A");
    assert(b.f() == "B");
}
```

In the above code, we are using [`alias this`](https://dlang.org/spec/class.html#alias-this) to create a kind of second inheritance chain. There are some problems with this, the  biggest that we can't cast from the thing returned from `get()` back to `C`.

This could be made more generic with UDAs and a mixin, such that this should compile and run:

```d
interface A { string f(); }
interface B { string f(); }
interface C { string f(); }
@implements!(B, C)
class D : A {
    string f() { return "A"; }
    @implements!(B.f)
    string bf() { return "B"; }
    @implements!(C.f)
    string cf() { return "C"; }
    mixin implement!();
}

unittest {
    D d = new D();
    A a = d;
    B b = d;
    C c = d;

    assert(a.f() == "A");
    assert(b.f() == "B");
    assert(c.f() == "C");

    assert(a == cast(A)d);
    assert(b == cast(B)d);
    assert(c == cast(C)d);
}
```

That, however, is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: so strange that something easy like this is not even possible, considering the amount of featues the language has

Comment: It's an issue that I have never faced in practice, and that sentiment has been echoed by others, so I think it's a very rare situation and might not be worth worrying about. Still, yeah.

Comment: with a big codebase it's quite easy to stumble upon this problem. Somehow it's indeed rare, but very possible. In a C++ project I work on it happened a few times.